# (27/8)^2/3 so how would i do this?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

$(27/8)^{-2/3}$
So please tell me how to simplify this.

I tried KFC (keep, flip, change) or KCF (Keep, change, flip),
where I kept $27/8$ as it is, then changed minus to a plus and then made $2/3$ into $3/2.$
I got $9/2.$

Please tell me if this is correct.
Much appreciated thanks.

Comment: What is the question ? Also, please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to write maths.

Comment: $\left(\frac32\right)^2$ isn't $\frac92$ but apart from that I think the method is correct. Try and write it out line by line as your description is hard to follow

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 3):

If you tried KFC (Kentucky Fried Chicken) you would know it's good.

For a few hints, you can use the following facts (edit: added #3):

1. $$a^{-b} = \displaystyle\frac{1}{a^b}$$
2. $$a^{b/c} = \left(\sqrt[c]{a}\right)^b$$
3. $$(a/b)^c = \displaystyle\frac{a^c}{b^c}$$